# Function to evenly distribute results in fixed number of buckets

Tags: c++, distribution

I'm looking for a nifty solution for the following problem:

I got X number of structs that is identified with a unique 64 bit integer that can have any value. I would like to evenly distribute them into a pre-defined number of buckets, without knowing all the min/max id values when starting out and without moving any values.

So far the best solution I can come up with is an lookup map where bucket id is key and value is a list of struct id number.

Just wanted to check if someone have a better solution on this problem (?)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: presumably round robin is out?

Answer (score 1):

That you're postulating a lookup map from bucket id to a list of unique ids representing individual structs implies you have no interest in finding the structs using those unique ids.  If that's true, then it seems your problem would be how to get the proper number of elements in each bucket... you can do that by incrementing a bucket counter across the buckets - wrapping from last to first when necessary - and assigning successive structures into the associated bucket.

Still, I suspect you've probably not expressed your real needs accurately, and may need to find structures using those unique ids?  If that's true, then a crucial question is whether you just need a statistically equally likely chance of any given struct ending up associated with any given bucket (such that the structs-per-bucket approximates and averages #structs/#buckets but there will be fluctuation), or do you need it exact.  In the former case, a hash map sounds appropriate.  Otherwise, I can't think of a particularly good solution.  Perhaps worth mentioning that you can have pointers to values and move the pointers around to achieve some load balancing while avoid moving the actual objects.